# The development server returned response error code: 500 react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, navigation, yarnpkg

Error on the node.js window:
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-gesture-handler` from `node_modules\@react-navigation\native\src\Scrollables.js`: react-native-gesture-handler could not be found within the project.

I think the error is related to libraries of the npm or the yarn.

App.js code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class FirstPage extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>This is the first page.</Text>
        <Button onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('test')} title="Go to the second page"/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class SecondPage extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>This is the second page.</Text>
        <Button onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('home')} title="Go to the first page"/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default createStackNavigator({
  home:FirstPage,
  test:SecondPage
});
```

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the below packages along with raeact navigation for it to work ,

you can add by

```
yarn add react-navigation react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens
```

or

```
npm i react-navigation react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install `react-native-gesture-handler` because `react-navaigation` used it. So for more explanation you can go trough the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/

Comment: Yeah. The react native docs has the answer. Thanks a ton! @Patrissol Kenfack